# npm throws EACCES error on installation of Angular CLI - Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Tags: angular, macos, npm

> npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4
> <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js
> environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
> (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797) npm WARN deprecated
> request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated
> har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported npm WARN
> checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
> npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! path
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! errno -13

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then you are prompted to enter your password, do so and the installation shall proceed as expected.

Also read this article [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)